# Prestashop 1.6 Paypal Module: Customer getting payment error even that payment success

Tags: paypal, prestashop, payment

Customer getting payment error even that payment success.
Everything going good from cart -> paypal payment method -> paypal site -> back to my shop.
but here (he gets email also about the problem), instead of getting greeting message that we got the payment and ready to ship his order, the customer getting message that there was problem with the payment. In my end, I'm getting his payment.

Hope someone have idea how to figure it out, and I'll share any other details you need to solve this.
Thanks, Aviv.

Answer (score 0):

May I know is the email error is from PayPal or from your end?
If it is from PayPal, I recommend you to file a technical support ticket https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/

Do provide the email and the affected transaction ID for further checking